# Android Shorten and encrypt Xml-Code

Tags: java, android, xml, encryption, reduce

If the user wants, the app can output xml-code from the data the app has.
For example:

```
<Week>
  <Monday>I went to the cinema</Monday>
  ...
</Week>
```

This xml code he can use to share to others which can input it in the app.
The problem is: This xml-code can be very long. So I would like to shorten and encrypt it. 
So the requirements are:

- The treated-code is not readable anymore for the user
- The code is (very) short

How can I do that?
P.S. Before you ask: Yes I know basic encryption (Caesar, Cipher, ...). But I dont know how to reduce that code.

Comment: Compress it using a standard compression algorithm (e.g., ZIP). Do not consider encryption until you know *exactly* who the threats are. IOW, who are you trying to defend the data from?

Comment: I dont want the user to customize the data by hand. Moreover I dont want to see other apps copying what I do.

Comment: "I dont want the user to customize the data by hand" -- it is the user's data, not yours.

Comment: Its not as easy as the example above. it contains dates in millis and so on.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I implemented AES to encrypt and decrypt the code. but I also read there is something called MD5 that makes a text unreadable. Is this the better way to go?